# Explore file system on hosted agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I have an Azure DevOps build that fails with an error that no files are found in a particular folder. If this build had run on-prem I would logon to the build server and explore the files and folder structure created by the build, in order to figure out what went wrong.

Is there a way to explore the build folder structure for a hosted agent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Work folder is the root for all of your Pipeline tasks whether it be artifact staging, repo, copy-files etc.

Run an in-line Powershell step with the following commands:

```
Set-Location $env:AGENT_WORKFOLDER
Get-ChildItem -Recurse
```

Check out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for some other common locations. Just search for `c:\agent_work` for all of the predefined variables that contain your files.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a PowerShell/Command Line task that go the agent folder and check the folders:

```
# Go to 's' folder in the agent - D:\a\1\s 
cd "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
dir
```

If you need deeper level you can add it of course:

```
cd "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Test/Etc"
dir
```

You can run the build, check the folders and if it's not enough then add more paths to check.

Or like jesse said in the comment, you can run `dir /b /s` to get all :)

Comment: Make that a `dir /b /s` and you get a list of all files in that directory and subdirectories.